# How to prevent Gson from converting a long number (a json string ) to scientific notation format?

Tags: java, json, gson

I need to convert json string to java object and display it as a long. The json string is a fixed array of long numbers:

```
{numbers
[ 268627104, 485677888, 506884800 ] }
```

The code to convert works fine in all cases except for numbers ending in 0. It converts those to a scientific notation number format:

```
   public static Object fromJson(HttpResponse response, Class<?> classOf)
    throws IOException {
    InputStream instream = response.getResponseInputStream();                   

    Object obj = null;
    try {
        Reader reader = new InputStreamReader(instream, HTTP.UTF_8);

        Gson gson = new Gson();

        obj = gson.fromJson(reader, classOf); 

        Logger.d(TAG, "json --> "+gson.toJson(obj));
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        Logger.e(TAG, "unsupported encoding", e);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Logger.e(TAG, "json parsing error", e);
    }

    return obj;
}
```

The actual result:
Java object :  268627104, 485677888, 5.068848E+8

Notice the last number is converted to a scientific notation format. Can anyone suggest what could be done to work around it or prevent it or undo it? I'm using Gson v1.7.1

Comment: Is it just numbers ending in 0, or does that third number cross some overflow boundary?

Comment: @BlackVegetable I only see this happening for numbers ending in 0. Other e.g. is  163341520 ->  1.6334152E+8. A larger number (10 digit number not ending in 0) is processed perfectly fine.

Comment: If it's a JSON *string* (enclosed in quotes) it won't be converted to scientific notation.  And have you examined the actual Java object types?  How do you know the difference is not simply in how a `double` is printed, depending on its value?

Answer (score 19):

If serializing to a String is an option for you, you can configure GSON to do so with:

```
GsonBuilder gsonBuilder = new GsonBuilder();
gsonBuilder.setLongSerializationPolicy( LongSerializationPolicy.STRING );
Gson gson = gsonBuilder.create();
```

This will produce something like:

```
{numbers : [ "268627104", "485677888", "506884800" ] }
```

Comment: This will convert to a string rather a long. Note the quotation marks

Comment: This only works with Long types. Integers, Decimals and Floats will still show without double quotes.

Comment: So apparently this option instructs gson to detect numbers that are long integers and convert them to strings.  Where is the policy to convert long integers to long integers?  Nothing against String or perhaps Map or Field, but it's a long integer. It's not a Map. It's not a String, It's not a Field. It's a long integer, so give me a long integer.

Answer (score 11):

Another work around is to use the JsonParser class instead. This will return the Gson object representations (JsonElement) rather than a user defined class, but avoids the problem of conversion to scientific notation.

```
import java.lang.reflect.Type;
import java.util.Map;

import com.google.gson.Gson;
import com.google.gson.JsonElement;
import com.google.gson.JsonParser;
import com.google.gson.reflect.TypeToken;

public class GsonTest
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        String json = "{numbers:[268627104,485677888,506884800]}";

        Gson gson = new Gson();
        Type type = new TypeToken<Map<String, Object>>(){}.getType();
        Map<String, Object> jsonMap = gson.fromJson(json, type);
        System.out.println("Gson output:");
        System.out.println(jsonMap);

        JsonParser jsonParser = new JsonParser();
        JsonElement jsonElement = jsonParser.parse(json);
        System.out.println("JsonParser output:");
        System.out.println(jsonElement);
    }
}
```

Code Output:

```
Gson output:  
{numbers=[2.68627104E8, 4.85677888E8, 5.068848E8]}  
JsonParser output:  
{"numbers":[268627104,485677888,506884800]}
```

Comment: The JsonParser approach shall work. I resorted to the format approach as my json string was very complicated and I had to extract each number before I could use it for display purpose.

Comment: It's just OUTPUT to String give you correct format, but if u try serialize class of this jsonElement i got not corrects Long values.

Comment: The [Gson Javadoc for JsonElement](http://google-gson.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/gson/docs/javadocs/index.html?com/google/gson/JsonElement.html) does not mention that class implementing serializable so I could see that being a problem. You could always transfer the data from the Gson object to your own object though.

Answer (score 8):

I had a similar problem, and it not only converts integers to double, but it actually loses precision for certain long numbers, as described in this [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17695242/179864).

I tracked down this conversion to `ObjectTypeAdapter`'s `read` method, specifically:

```java
case NUMBER:
  return in.nextDouble();
```

It may be possible to plug in a modified `TypeAdapter` for `Object`, but I couldn't get that to work, so instead I just copied the `read` method (`Object read(JsonReader in)`) to my own code and modified the above lines to this:

```
case NUMBER:
    final String s = in.nextString();
    try {
        return Integer.parseInt(s);
    } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
        // ignore
    }
    try {
        return Long.parseLong(s);
    } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
        // ignore
    }
    return Double.parseDouble(s);
```

I wish Gson did this by default..

Then I put the other connecting pieces in a helper method that looks something like this:

```
public static Object parse(final Reader r) {
    try (final JsonReader jr = new JsonReader(r)) {
        jr.setLenient(true);
        boolean empty = true;
        Object o = null;
        try {
            jr.peek();
            empty = false;
            o = read(jr);
        } catch (EOFException e) {
            if (!empty) {
                throw new JsonSyntaxException(e);
            }
        }
        if (o != null && jr.peek() != JsonToken.END_DOCUMENT) {
            throw new JsonIOException("JSON document was not fully consumed.");
        }
        return o;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        throw new JsonIOException(e);
    }
}
```

So now instead of `new Gson().fromJson(r, Object.class)`, I call `parse(r)`.

This works well for me because I want to be able to parse json data with any structure, but if you have a particular class you're targeting, you probably just need to eliminate occurrences of `Object` within that class's members.

Answer (score 5):

Got the same issue, after some investigation here is what I found.

**The behavior:**

- Gson
  For a number without fractional part, `Gson` would convert it as `Double`,
- Jackson
  For a number without fractional part, `Jackson` would convert it as `Integer` or `Long`, depends on how large the number is.

**Possible solutions:**

- Convert `Gson`'s return value from `Double` to `Long`, explicitly.
- Use `Jackson` instead.
  I prefer this.

---

**Code - test for `Jackson`**

**ParseNumberTest.java:**

```
import java.util.List;

import org.testng.Assert;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;

/**
 * test - jackson parse numbers,
 * 
 * @author eric
 * @date Jan 13, 2018 12:28:36 AM
 */
public class ParseNumberTest {
    @Test
    public void test() throws Exception {
    String jsonFn = "numbers.json";

    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

    DummyData dd = mapper.readValue(this.getClass().getResourceAsStream(jsonFn), DummyData.class);
    for (Object data : dd.dataList) {
        System.out.printf("data type: %s, value: %s\n", data.getClass().getName(), data.toString());
        Assert.assertTrue(data.getClass() == Double.class || data.getClass() == Long.class || data.getClass() == Integer.class);

        System.out.printf("%s\n\n", "------------");
    }
    }

    static class DummyData {
    List<Object> dataList;

    public List<Object> getDataList() {
        return dataList;
    }

    public void setDataList(List<Object> dataList) {
        this.dataList = dataList;
    }
    }
}
```

**numbers.json:**

```
{
    "dataList": [
        150000000000,
        150778742934,
        150000,
        150000.0
    ]
}
```

**How to run:**

- The test case is based on `Jackson` & `TestNG`.
- Put `numbers.json` at the same package as `ParseNumberTest.java`.
- Run as testng test, then it would print type & value of the parse result.

**Output:**

```
data type: java.lang.Long, value: 150000000000
------------

data type: java.lang.Long, value: 150778742934
------------

data type: java.lang.Integer, value: 150000
------------

data type: java.lang.Double, value: 150000.0
------------

PASSED: test
```

Answer (score 1):

We can use the below code solution for number Long:

```
Document doc = documentCursor.next();  

JsonWriterSettings relaxed = JsonWriterSettings.builder().outputMode(JsonMode.RELAXED).build();  

CustomeObject obj = gson.fromJson(doc.toJson(relaxed), CustomeObject.class);
```

Comment: Thanks !!! It solves my problem with NumberLong object instead long property into the pojo.

Answer (score 0):

Not smart, but still working method is to add " at the start and at the end of the number. Then after processing is finished, delete it.

Answer (score 0):

The best solution in case you need them as String was to force attributes to be quoted with a single quote before doing the conversion.

Do changes like this:

```
String readerAsString = convertReaderToString(reader);
readerAsString = readerAsString.toString().replace("=", "='");
readerAsString = readerAsString.toString().replace(",", "',");
readerAsString = readerAsString.toString().replace("}]", "'}]");
```

Answer (score 0):

```kotlin
data class Answer(
    val question: String,
    val value: Any
)
```

Given the `value:Any` property above, I find it dubious that Gson encounters a JSON value of `1` (not `"1"`) and cannot INFER the blatantly obvious truth: `1` is an `Int`.  Instead, Gson converts the integer value to the double `1.0`.

Gson *should* only convert a JSON value from `1` to `1.0` if the `value` property above was of type `Float` or `Double`. When Gson encounters a property whose type is `Any`, it should (quite simply) infer the type from the JSON value it receives. Unfortunately, it doesn't, preferring to actually corrupt incoming integer values by casting them to Double, which unsurprisingly immediately causes exceptions.

I can find no reasonable solution to this peculiarity of the Gson parser. As such, I'm forced to either manually convert all those double values back into int values after using Gson or implement my own generic custom type adapter for Gson. Neither of these options is at all appealing.

Answer (score -1):

I did not find a solution to my problem of gson formatting numbers ending in 0 to scientific notation. I instead used a work-around to convert this scientific notation into a double that I formatted with commas. "value" is the json string.

```
  private String formatNumber(String value) { 
    double dValue = Double.parseDouble(value);
    String pattern = "#,###";
    DecimalFormat formatter = new DecimalFormat(pattern);
    String newNumber = formatter.format(dValue);

            return newNumber;
}
```

This doesn't answer the question asked but is an added step to work-around the problem to display the numbers as required by the system.

Comment: This is not safe.  The significand precision is 52 bits.  You will lose information this way.  This becomes a problem when you are using the long as an ID value where precision matters.

Comment: To preserve precision one can use BigDecimal from java.math. Also Gson can internally handle scientific and regular notations.