# Converting JSON string to Java Object: Java

Tags: java, json, gson

I have a String

```
String aString = "[{code:32022,estCode:0,timeZone:CE},{code:59400,estCode:0,timeZone:CE},{code:59377,estCode:0,timeZone:CE},{code:59525,estCode:0,timeZone:CE},{code:59560,estCode:0,timeZone:CE}]"
```

I am trying to convert this string to `Map[]` using gson.

I tried using

```
Gson gsn = new GsonBuilder().create();
Map[] b = gsn.fromJson(aString , Map[].class);
```

I am able to parse it properly and I am getting output as

```
[{code=32022.0, estCode=0.0, timeZone=CE}, {code=59400.0, estCode=0.0, timeZone=CE}, {code=59377.0, estCode=0.0, timeZone=CE}, {code=59525.0, estCode=0.0, timeZone=CE}, {code=59560.0, estCode=0.0, timeZone=CE}]
```

but the values are converted to double i need it as String.
Ex: 32022 is converted to 32022.0 i need it as 32022 is there any way i can do it using `ExclusionStrategy` in gson. I am seeing only two methos availalbe in `ExclusionStrategy, shouldSkipClass and shouldSkipField` is there any other way to do it using gson.

Please help

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Gson. Deserialize integers as integers and not as doubles](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17090589/gson-deserialize-integers-as-integers-and-not-as-doubles)

Comment: map follow key value but you have 3 attribute in your json element {code:32022,estCode:0,timeZone:CE}, what kind of map you want.

Comment: @NikhiK.Bansal It is Map[]

Comment: @MichaelDibbets Is there any way to do it using gson

Comment: What is type of "code" field in Map object String or double? Can you provide code of Map Object.?

Comment: @Kishan It is object and Map is java.util.Map

Comment: You can create your own object and give it to Gson. Make "code" as String in your object.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to change the type of the values, but you could use an own class for that like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        String aString = "[{code:32022,estCode:0,timeZone:CE},{code:59400,estCode:0,timeZone:CE},{code:59377,estCode:0,timeZone:CE},{code:59525,estCode:0,timeZone:CE},{code:59560,estCode:0,timeZone:CE}]";
        Gson gsn = new GsonBuilder().create();
        TimeCode[] b =  gsn.fromJson(aString, TimeCode[].class);
        for(TimeCode entry:b){
                System.out.print(entry+",");
        }

    }

    class TimeCode{
        String code;
        String estCode;
        String timeZone;

        public String toString(){
            return "code="+code+",estCode="+estCode+",timeZone="+timeZone;
        }
    }
```

Output:

```
code=32022,estCode=0,timeZone=CE,code=59400,estCode=0,timeZone=CE,code=59377,estCode=0,timeZone=CE,code=59525,estCode=0,timeZone=CE,code=59560,estCode=0,timeZone=CE,
```

I hope it helps.