# Gson Long lost data when parse from String

Tags: java, gson

I have json string represenatation of some object
class objects is

```
public class SMPBBaseObjectsList {

    public ArrayList<Object> data = new ArrayList<>();
    public Integer count;
    public Integer limitFrom;
    public Integer limitTo;
    public Boolean hasMore;
    public String dataItemsClass;
}
```

And i have json

> {"classItem":"smpb.utility.classes.SMPBBaseObjectsList","dataItemsClass":"smpb.base.classes.SMPBUser","dataSliceCode":"012013","data":[{"id":1374046117510970000,"Name":"Test3","classItem":"smpb.base.classes.SMPBUser","dataSliceCode":"012013"}],"filter":{"orderItems":[],"filterItems":[]}}

I try parse this json and create object of my class with next code:

```
 String json = "{\"classItem\":\"smpb.utility.classes.SMPBBaseObjectsList\",\"dataItemsClass\":\"smpb.base.classes.SMPBUser\",\"dataSliceCode\":\"012013\",\"data\":[{\"id\":1374046117510970000,\"Name\":\"Test3\",\"classItem\":\"smpb.base.classes.SMPBUser\",\"dataSliceCode\":\"012013\"}],\"filter\":{\"orderItems\":[],\"filterItems\":[]}}";
        SMPBBaseObjectsList list = new GsonBuilder().create().fromJson(json, SMPBBaseObjectsList.class);
        System.out.println("BEFORE:" + json);
        System.out.println("AFTER: " + list);
```

**System outputs:**

> **BEFORE:**{"classItem":"smpb.utility.classes.SMPBBaseObjectsList","dataItemsClass":"smpb.base.classes.SMPBUser","dataSliceCode":"012013","data":[{**"id":1374044905885298000**,"Name":"Test3","classItem":"smpb.base.classes.SMPBUser","dataSliceCode":"012013"}],"filter":{"orderItems":[],"filterItems":[]}}
>
> **AFTER:** {"classItem":"smpb.utility.classes.SMPBBaseObjectsList","dataItemsClass":"smpb.base.classes.SMPBUser","dataSliceCode":"012013","data":[{"Name":"Test3",**"id":1.374044905885298011E18**,"classItem":"smpb.base.classes.SMPBUser","dataSliceCode":"012013"}],"filter":{"orderItems":[],"filterItems":[]}}

As u can see in Json String i have ID with value 1374044905885298000 , but when object serialized from string i got 1.374044905885298011E18

And problem is what this representation of Long lost last zeros 0000 and i got Long 1374044905885297920

Why? and how fix it?

Data in Array is String map, and it's already all Long id Double format.

I try registerAdapater for Long or Double but never triggered.

Version of Gson 2.2.4

**UPDATE**

It's not duplicate of question

[How to prevent Gson from converting a long number (a json string ) to scientific notation format?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11586299/how-to-prevent-gson-from-converting-a-long-number-a-json-string-to-scientific)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to prevent Gson from converting a long number (a json string ) to scientific notation format?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11586299/how-to-prevent-gson-from-converting-a-long-number-a-json-string-to-scientific)

Comment: It's not. If you read anwsers u will found what it's not soluction of deserialization, it's jus STRING representation. but if u try deserialize JsonElement jsonElement = jsonParser.parse(json); to class u got my error.

Comment: To fix it, you can write a custom deserializer class. Take a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5845822/gson-deserializing-key-value-to-custom-object

Answer (score 0):

I can't tell exactly what the problem is, but you can solve it by creating another class, i.e. `Data` to use in the `List` instead of the `Object` class... I tried this code and it's working fine for me!

So, you need to replace the `ArrayList<Object>` in your `SMPBBaseObjectsList` by:

```
public ArrayList<Data> data = new ArrayList<>()
```

And create a new class like this:

```
public class Data {    
    public Long id;
    public String Name;
    public String classItem;
    public String dataSliceCode;
}
```

I guess there's an issue when parsing the JSON to an `Object` object, it probably makes some conversion that leads to that number formatting, but unfortunately I'm not an expert in this Java low-level issues... 

Anyway, with this code you are explicitly specifying that you want that value parsed into a `Long`, so there's no problem!

Comment: My probles is that Data is Array of Objects because it's containts different classes

Comment: @DmitryNelepov: You can always create the `Data` class containing all the attributes of all the classes the `Array` can contain and it will be able to parse all the possible classes... or you can create a custom deserializer for that part...