# Android Convert String to JSONObject

Tags: android, json

I want to convert a string to JSONObject. Below is sample code.

```
String str = "{"time": 1449838598.0999202, "Label": "Shirt", "Price": 52}";
JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(str);
```

But after conversion time becomes 1.4498385980999203E9. 
Any Help will be appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: Write it like this"1449838598.0999202" in double quotes

Comment: What command are you using to retrieve the "time" attribute?

Comment: I dont see anything wrong with scientific notation

Comment: Try adding the escape character in your string initialization: `String str = "{\"time\": 1449838598.0999202, \"Label\": \"Shirt\", \"Price\": 52}";`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you really want it to be formatted like that then make it into a string instead of a number.  Just add double quotes around the item. But if your using it for a calculation on the other end, i would leave it as is as you'll have to convert it back to a int anyway.     If you want to use gson as an alternative check here: [How to prevent Gson from converting a long number (a json string ) to scientific notation format?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11586299/how-to-prevent-gson-from-converting-a-long-number-a-json-string-to-scientific)

Answer (score 2):

Write it like this in double quote. "1449838598.0999202"

Answer (score 1):

Like Abhishek said, write time & price in double quote as "1449838598.0999202" and "52".
Then you can save the string to Gson, and then convert it to Json.

```
String str = "{"time": "1449838598.0999202", "Label": "Shirt", "Price": "52"}";
Gson gson = new Gson();
String json = gson.toJson(str);
```